# Ajax inconsistent timeout behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web app that I've added a simple ajax call to give the network connection status. It works as expected with a good connection, the problem is when it fails.

I'm using the osx network link conditioner (nlc) to simulate a bad connection. I would expect that as I increase the delay in the nlc that the ajax request would take longer, up until 30 secs when it should timeout. Sometimes I do see it timing out as expected, other times it fails earlier (for example 18 secs, but I would still expect it to go to 30 secs). The error messages are of no help either, it just says "error".

The behaviour is inconsistent so it's hard to nail down what is happening. It's hosted on an apache server, I changed the keep-alive timeout to 60 seconds, so that should be plenty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ping test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" onclick= "checkNetworkStatus(); return false;">Ping test!</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkNetworkStatus() {
    // Time how long the call to the server takes
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();

    if (navigator.onLine) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (request, status, err) {
                console.log("request:" + request + " status:" + status + " err:" + err);

                // Measure data gathering time
                var request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
                console.log(request_time);
            },
            success: function (data, status, req) {
                console.log("Ping success!");

                // Measure data gathering time
                var request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
                console.log(request_time);
            },
            timeout: 30000,
            type: "GET",
            url: "js/ping.js"
        });

    }
    else {
        console.log("Not connected to network!");
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ping.js is just this:

```
{ "status": "Online" }
```

Similar to this question [jQuery ajax txtStat does not return "timeout" but "error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713471/jquery-ajax-txtstat-does-not-return-timeout-but-error?rq=1) but in my case the connection is just slowed never completely shut off.

Comment: Sorry accidentally posted the question before I finished it.

Comment: huh? Why? It should be the full question now.

Comment: If your timings are off, then first thing would be to take pageload out of picture by adding `$(document).ready();`. Also, there should be a solution for avoiding multiple calls. If multiple calls would go out, then timeout becomes more often.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this is just a test page which I'm running manually so am making sure it's fully loaded and only one at a time.